# How do you create a multi-dimensional crosstab with per-dimension totals in Pyspark efficiently?

Tags: pyspark, aggregate, pivot-table

### TL;DR: Is there a better approach than this?

```
columns = ['sex', 'class', 'survived'] # for many columns
grouped_crosstab = sdf.groupBy(*columns).count()

for column in columns:
    grouped_crosstab = grouped_crosstab.join(
        grouped_crosstab.groupBy(column).agg(F.sum('count').alias(f'{column}_total')),
        column,
        'left')
```

---

### Problem Setup

In Pyspark, you can use the `crosstab` method on a `DataFrame` to get a two-dimensional cross tabulation of your data. Similarly, the `groupBy` methods can return a multi-dimensional "crosstab" of your data, though it is in a tall and skinny format.

For example:

```
columns = ['x', 'y', 'z'] # columns are assumed to be rather low in cardinality, such as categorical values, not continuous values
two_dimensional_crosstab = df.crosstab(columns[0], columns[1]) # only compares 'x' and 'y'
multi_dimensional_view = df.groupBy(*columns).count() # compares 'x', 'y', and 'z'
```

### Let's visualize this with some example data

```
import seaborn
df = seaborn.load_dataset('titanic')
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df) # how to setup a spark context is outside the scope of this question
```

The data looks like this:

[image: The titanic dataset as shown in Spark]

Let's create a two dimensional crosstab on `sex` and `class`, and let's use both the `crosstab` and the `groupBy` functions to show how the two methods compare:

```
two_d_crosstab = sdf.crosstab('sex', 'class')
grouped_crosstab = sdf.groupBy('sex', 'class').count()
```

These dataframes look like this:

[image: Two dimensional crosstabs]

Unlike `crosstab`, the `groupBy` methodology generalizes well to multiple columns, but one must take care in the formatting of the table.

### Column and Row totals

It is common to want to have row and column sums on a crosstab for statistical purposes, for example, survey raking. In the two dimensional case, one can get such information through this (admittedly convoluted) approach:

```
index_column = two_d_crosstab.columns[0]
col_list = two_d_crosstab.columns[1:]
two_d_crosstab = two_d_crosstab.withColumn('column_total', sum([F.col(c) for c in col_list]))
transposed_df = two_d_crosstab.pandas_api()\
    .set_index(index_column)\
    .T.reset_index()\
    .rename(columns = {'index':index_column})\
    .to_spark()
col_list = transposed_df.columns[1:]
two_d_crosstab = transposed_df.withColumn('row_total', sum([F.col(c) for c in col_list]))
```

The `two_d_crosstab` looks like this:

[image: Two dim crosstab with row and column totals]

### Multi-dimensional totals

How does one make this calculation on a multi-dimensional cross-tab?

Here is what I have tried:

```
sex_tot = grouped_crosstab.groupBy('sex').agg(F.sum('count').alias('sex_total'))
class_tot = grouped_crosstab.groupBy('class').agg(F.sum('count').alias('class_total'))
grouped_crosstab = grouped_crosstab.join(sex_tot, 'sex', 'left').join(class_tot, 'class', 'left')
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Two dimensional crosstab with totals created by group by]

Let's add `survived` as a third dimension:

```
columns = ['sex', 'class', 'survived']
grouped_crosstab = sdf.groupBy(*columns).count()

for column in columns:
    grouped_crosstab = grouped_crosstab.join(
        grouped_crosstab.groupBy(column).agg(F.sum('count').alias(f'{column}_total')),
        column,
        'left')
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Three dimensional crosstab with per-dimension counts]

Note that there is a lot of repetitive information in the output. As the number of columns increases, the number of group by and join operations increases, so this will get rather unwieldy, especially on large data frames with millions of rows.

*Is there a better (more scaleable) way?*

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at a solution (which I discovered while writing this question) is to use the `cube` method instead of `groupBy`. Starting with the two-dimensional case:

```
columns = ['sex', 'class']
cubed_crosstab = sdf.cube(*columns).count()
```

Produces:

[image: Cubed output two dimensions]

Where, when a `null` is shown, the count is treated as a "don't care about the value in this column". So, on the third row of the screenshot, the count of 491 is for Third class passengers of any sex, and row 5 produces a total for the entire data frame. Note that these counts align with the counts produced earlier.

Generalizing to multiple dimensions is trivial:

```
columns = ['sex', 'class', 'survived']
cubed_crosstab = sdf.cube(*columns).count()
```

[image: Three dimensional crosstab with counts by cube]

### Limitation of this answer

The answer becomes ambiguous when there are null values in both columns. For example:

```
columns = ['deck', 'embarked']
cubed_crosstab = sdf.cube(*columns).count()
```

[image: Ambiguous result]

There are duplicate entries with different counts. Null can represent the "don't care" state, or it could represent a legitimate value in the data. It is advised to recode nulls to another value prior to `cubeing` (is that a word?) to avoid this ambiguity.